# C# Reflection - Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to use the `propertyInfo.SetValue()` method to set an object property value with reflection, and I'm getting the exception "Object does not match target type".  It doesn't really make sense (at least to me!) as I'm just trying to set a simple string property on an object with a string replacement value.  Here's a code snippet - this is contained within a recursive function so there's a bunch more code, but this is the guts:

```
PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = businessObject.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.ToLower() == piecesLeft[0].ToLower());
businessObject = fieldPropertyInfo.GetValue(businessObject, null);

fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(businessObject, replacementValue, null);
```

I've verified that `businessObject" and`replacementValue` are both the same type by doing this comparison, which returned true:

```
businessObject.GetType() == replacementValue.GetType()
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're trying to set the value of the propertyinfo value's. Because you're overwriting the `businessObject`

```
PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = businessObject.GetType().GetProperties()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.ToLower() == piecesLeft[0].ToLower());

// The result should be stored into another variable here:
businessObject = fieldPropertyInfo.GetValue(businessObject, null);

fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(businessObject, replacementValue, null);
```

It should be something like:

```
PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = businessObject.GetType().GetProperties()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.ToLower() == piecesLeft[0].ToLower());

// also you should check if the propertyInfo is assigned, because the 
// given property looks like a variable.
if(fieldPropertyInfo == null)
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Property {0} not found", f.Name.ToLower()));

// you are overwriting the original businessObject
var businessObjectPropValue = fieldPropertyInfo.GetValue(businessObject, null);

fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(businessObject, replacementValue, null);
```

Comment: bingo - thanks for the clear and concise code sample.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you just want to remove the second line. What's it doing there anyway? You're fetching the value of the property *from* the object referred to by `businessObject` - and setting that to the new value of `businessObject`. So if this really is a string property, the value of `businessObject` will be a string reference afterwards - and you're then trying to use that as the target for *setting* the property! It's a bit like doing this:

```
dynamic businessObject = ...;
businessObject = businessObject.SomeProperty; // This returns a string, remember!
businessObject.SomeProperty = replacementValue;
```

That's not going to work.

It's not clear what `replacementValue` is - whether it's the replacement string or a business object to fetch the real replacement value from, but I suspect you either want:

```
PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = businessObject.GetType().GetProperties()
      .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.ToLower() == piecesLeft[0].ToLower());
fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(businessObject, replacementValue, null);
```

Or:

```
PropertyInfo fieldPropertyInfo = businessObject.GetType().GetProperties()
      .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.ToLower() == piecesLeft[0].ToLower());
object newValue = fieldPropertyInfo.GetValue(replacementValue, null);
fieldPropertyInfo.SetValue(businessObject, newValue, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to set the value of the *property on businessObject* to another value of the type of `businessObject`, not the type of that property.

For this code to work, `replacementValue` needs to be the same type as the field defined by `piecesLeft[0]`, and it obviously is not that type.